# change the content of a div from inside a javascript class

Tags: javascript, class

Hello dear coding buddies,

I have a problem:

Im trying to change the content of a div with the results of a method in a class i made. Somehow i keep ending up with null. I am probably doing something conceptually wrong but i have no idea what since i am pretty new to javascript.

This is my code so far:

```
class Virus {
  constructor(population) {
    this.mortalityPercentage = 0.023;
    this.period = 1;
    this.infectionRate = 2;
    this.infected = 1;
    this.population = population;
  }
  calculate() {
    while (this.infected < this.population) {
      this.period += 6;
      console.log(this.period);
      this.infected *= this.infectionRate;
      console.log(this.infected);
      this.dead = this.infected * this.mortalityPercentage;
      console.log(this.dead);
    }
  }
  render() {
        document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = this.period;
        document.getElementById('infected').innerHTML = this.infected;
        document.getElementById('dead').innerHTML = this.dead;
  }
};

let virus = new Virus(7760000000);
virus.calculate();
virus.render();

How many days does it take to infect the world?
<div id="days">

</div>
Number of infected people:
<div id="infected">

</div>
I see dead people:
<div id="dead">

</div>
```

This is the error message i get on jsFiddle:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at Virus.render ((index):55)
    at (index):63
Ideally i would like a counter making use of setInterval or requestAnimationFrame but i have no idea how. Can you please help?

Comment: I just [copy/pasted your code into codepen](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/bGNydRa) and added the HTML with the ID's described in your JS and it is giving me non-null results. What does your HTML look like? Where are you seeing null?

Comment: Hi Stephen im playing with this on jsFiddle. I've added the html below the class.

Comment: I found out why i got the error: i needed to use pure javascript on jsFiddle while i was using javascript+jquery 3.41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setInterval` could go in a bunch of places, but it's probably most clear to put it in around your function calls:

```
setInterval( () => {
  virus.calculate();
  virus.render();
}, 250)
```

Now the calculate and render methods will be executed every **250ms**

You can replace the `while` inside your calculate with an `if` since it will be evaluated every time the function is called

```
calculate() {
  if (this.infected < this.population) {
    this.period += 6;
    this.infected *= this.infectionRate;
    this.dead = this.infected * this.mortalityPercentage;
  }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/yodjf14v/3/

Alternatively, you could put the `setInterval` inside the `calculate()` function and have it call `render()`:

```
calculate() {
  setInterval( () => {
    if (this.infected < this.population) {
      this.period += 6;
      this.infected *= this.infectionRate;
      this.dead = this.infected * this.mortalityPercentage;
      this.render(); // Here's the render call
    }
  }, 250)
}
```

For extra goodness, make the 250ms in your `setInterval` a property of the you class like `this.interval = 250;`. Having the value in the middle of the code is known as a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) and is often considered bad practice.

`requestAnimationFrame` probably wouldn't be a good match for your use case here because you don't have direct control over when it runs (ie: every n milliseconds). It's generally more used for animation when you want to repaint as often as possible.

You could always throttle your function calls within it by storing the last called time and comparing it to the current time, but for this use case it would just be `setInterval` with more steps

Comment: Yes! Thats exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: @MartijnvanderBruggen no problem!

Comment: Great answer btw!